# LADR Ed 4, column rank = row rank proof

Tags: linear-algebra

In the proof, Axler says that:

column rank $A=$ row rank $A^t \leq$ column rank $A^t=$ row rank $A$

I don't understand why:

row rank $A^t \leq$ column rank $A^t$

Explain, please

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the proof of 3.57 (as should have been stated in your question). The first paragraph of the proof of 3.57 proves that
$$
\text{row rank of } A \le \text{column rank of } A 
$$
for every matrix $A$.

The second paragraph of the proof of 3.57 (from which you are quoting) begins by asking the reader to apply the result in the previous paragraph to $A^t$. In other words, replacing $A$ by $A^t$ in the inequality above, we have
$$
\text{row rank of } A^t \le \text{column rank of } A^t,
$$
as desired.